# Wiremock Stand alone - How to manipulate response with request data

Tags: java, mocking, stub, wiremock

I was trying to implement mocking of POST REST call using Wiremock Standalone server. I am faced with a challenge like this, suppose the post body contains an "name" field and its value, the same value should be returned in the response of that POST call. My json file looks like this:

```
{
"priority": 1,
"request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "urlPath": "/primeSlots",
    "bodyPatterns" : [ {
        "matchesJsonPath" : "{ \"things\": [ { \"name\": \"794363\" }] 
 }"
    } ]
 },
 "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "body": "{{$.things.name.value}}",
    "transformers": ["response-template"]
 }
}
```

so, I need to get the value , that is 794363,but using above approach not able to get it in the post response body.

I tried this too:

```
{
 "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "urlPath": "/transform",
    "bodyPatterns": [
        {
            "matchesJsonPath" : "$.things[?(@.name =~ /[0-9]+/i)]"
        }
    ]
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "body": "{\"responseName\": \"
   {{request.body.things.name.value}}\"}",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "transformers": ["body-transformer"]
  }
 }
```

So my question is, even if i use a regEx, which matches with any number that comes in the request, how to give back the same number in the response using Wiremock standalone json file?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Today I was in the same situation like you and found a solution which I would like to share with you:

1. Create own class that extends `ResponseDefinitionTransformer`
2. Add Handlebar functionality in your own transformer class ( see https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java how to do it )
3. (Optional) Append your own/other helpers e.g. 
   `Arrays.stream(StringHelpers.values()).forEach(helper -> this.handlebars.registerHelper(helper.name(), helper));`
4. Export your transformer customization as a separate JAR file
5. Create a start batch script to start up your WireMock standalone with your own transformer extension e.g. `java -cp "-cp ".\lib\wiremock-standalone-2.5.1.jar;.\lib\customTransformer.jar" com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.WireMockServerRunner --extensions "your.name.CustomTransformer"` (for linux use `:` instead of `;` as classpath separator)

In case you have multiple transformers, just define all those using  `,` (comma) as separator in the `--extensions` arg.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately WireMock's response templating transformer doesn't currently break out the request body into a Map as would be necessary for what you're trying to do. The request body is just a single string.

The simplest way for you to enable this would probably be to write a Handlebars helper that implements JSONPath or some other mechanism for querying a JSON document, then registering this with the templating transformer when you initialise WireMock.

At some point I'll write handlebars helpers to do this kind of thing for XML and JSON, but that won't be for a while.

Comment: Hi Tom. JKnack gives us a good example when creating Handlebars helpers with [StringHelpers](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java/blob/master/handlebars/src/main/java/com/github/jknack/handlebars/helper/StringHelpers.java) but when reading documentation on [WireMock Extension](http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/) it's difficult to understand how the two are related (specially when running in standalone). Does adding a helper require a new ResponseDefinitionTransformer as well?

Comment: No, you won't need to write an extension. Just activate the response templating extension in code and add a standard Handlebars helper (http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/#custom-helpers).

Comment: Thanks Tom, I did see that part of the docs, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this in standalone mode, am I right? Perhaps an opportunity to contribute? BTW, absolutely love WireMock, thank you for this tool!

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to re-bake your own standalone JAR if you want to do that unfortunately.

And thanks!

Comment: The C# version (WireMock.Net) does support this functionality. You can use `bodyAsJson`. For more details see https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/wiki/Stubbing-and-Request-Matching#the-request-model

Comment: There's a Handlebars helper in WireMock now for querying a JSON document using JSONPath, so no need to write a custom transformer/helper any more.

Comment: @Tom, I tried using `"foo": "{{jsonPath request.body '$.outer'}}"` in the response.jsonBody in a stub.json file, but I get that literal string; no substitution. Did I miss something obvious?

Comment: @Alecz I suspect you've forgotten to enable templating when starting WireMock