# wiremock how to get post data

Tags: java, post, wiremock

i'm trying to get data from the post does any one try

{
    "name":"sasha",
    "age":"15",
    "country":"italy"
}

I will like to get the value sash from the post, any ideas?

---

only find to reply...

http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/
buy I don't want to reply, I want the data.

---

I would like something linke this:

String name = wiremock.withRequestBody(name());
print name -> sasha

something like this:
Body postBody = aResponse().withBody(matching("[?(@.name]"));

---

I'm trying to get data from the POST like curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{'json':{'name':'sasha'}}" 127.0.0.1:8080/to/post I want to get sasha

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wiremock Stand alone - How to manipulate response with request data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073991/wiremock-stand-alone-how-to-manipulate-response-with-request-data)

Comment: that is for transforming response in templates

Comment: so far i have understand you have to convert response to template otherwise there is no direct way to manipulate response.

Comment: I'm not working in the response level, I'm using the POST parameters..
header, body..

Comment: you are trying to make a post request?

Comment: No I'm trying to get data from the POST
like  curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{'json':{'name':'sasha'}}" http://127.0.0.1:8080/to/post/

I want to get sasha

Comment: Do you want to use that value (`Sasha`) in the response? Or do you want to make a rule that is triggered whenever there is a message containing `"Name": "Sasha"`?

Comment: I want a rule to trigger when receive from the POST "name":"Sasha"